# How to add a customised \contentsname as an entry in \tableofcontents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I want the `\contentsname` to be "Table of Contents" and the same as an entry in the list of contents.

I'm using the `report` document class.
Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, titlepage, openright]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Some Title}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}

    \maketitle

    \cleardoublepage
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Table of Contents   \par}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
    \tableofcontents

    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

On running this, I get a lot of errors like the following:

```
Paragraph ended before \HyPsd@@ProtectSpacesFi was complete. ...dcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
Undefined control sequence. ...dcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
Use of \HyPsd@RemoveMask doesn't match its definition. ...dcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
Paragraph ended before \HyPsd@RemoveBraces was complete. ...dcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. ...dcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
```

But when I change the ordering of some lines to the following:

```
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centering Table of Contents   \par}
    \tableofcontents
```

There are no errors but of course the `\contentsname` has not been changed before adding to the `toc`

Comment: Table of contents in toc? What a strange idea! If you're reading the table of contents, you know where it is, by definition!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro `\contentsname` is destined for the contents name and *only* the contents name. You should not put `\centering` or `\par` there. And though if you use

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill Table of Contents \hspace*{\fill}}
```

It will work, but when you print the Contents name to the ToC using

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
```

The ToC entry will also be centered (try and see). If you use instead

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
```

All will be fine. But still, the proper/elegant way to do this is to modify the ToC style with a package such as the [tocloft](/questions/tagged/tocloft):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, titlepage, openright]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hspace*{\fill}}

\title{Some Title}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}

    \maketitle

    \cleardoublepage
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\contentsname}
    \tableofcontents

    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for the `\addtocontents` line. `\tableofcontents` will use your `\contentsname` anyway. But `\contentsname` is used also e.g. in headings and you will run into problems if you add commands like `\centering` there. Imho it is inconsequent to center the title of the table of contents but not the other chapters but if you really want it you should better patch `\tableofcontents`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, titlepage, openright]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Some Title}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\patchcmd\tableofcontents{\contentsname}{\hfill\contentsname\hfill\mbox{}}{}{\failed}
\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Very nice, `\patchcmd` is better! But still, perhaps the OP truly wants to put the ToC name in the ToC (belive me there are some crazy standards in the world).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to load `tocbibind`, which will also take care of the problem with the bibliography and the index (if you have one).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, titlepage, openright]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\title{Some Title}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\maketitle

\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage %%%<--- Don't forget this before \pagenumbering

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, having the table of contents listed in itself is usually not done. If you later decide against self-reference, just change the loading to

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

and run LaTeX twice.

If you want to center the title of the table of contents, some tricks are necessary; here's one based on `sectsty`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, titlepage, openright]{report}
\usepackage[left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\newcommand{\centertitleofcontents}{}
\chapterfont{\centertitleofcontents}

\title{Some Title}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\maketitle

\cleardoublepage

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\centertitleofcontents}{\centering}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\cleardoublepage % <--- Don't forget this before \pagenumbering

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```